# Passing an array to a prop to create multiple box-shadows

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

im trying to create a component whose css outputs a box-shadow with a number of shadows to create a stacked paper effect. Im trying to do this with styled-components. Not having much joy passing the css to the prop. Thanks in advance.

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'


const shadows = []

const shadowMixin = (shadow) => {
    let i ='';
    for(i = 0; i <= shadow; i++){
    shadows.push(`${i}px ${i}px ${i % 2 ? "red" : "black" }`)
    }        
}

shadowMixin(10)

console.log([...shadows].join(','))

const Input = styled.input.attrs(({ size }) => ({
    // we can define static props
    type: "password",

    // or we can define dynamic ones
    boxShadow: size || "2px 2px black"
  }))`
box-shadow: ${props => props.boxShadow}
`



// const Wrapper = styled.div`


// `
export default() => <Input size={[...shadows].join('')} />;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying your box shadow as an element attribute rather than as a style.

Try this instead:

```
const Input = styled.input.attrs(() => ({
  type: "password"
}))`
  box-shadow: ${props => props.boxShadow || "2px 2px black"};
`
```

...and then pass the **boxShadow** prop:

```
export default () => <Input boxShadow={[...shadows].join('')} />
```

Comment: No problem, glad it helped you out :)